# How can I remove a stuck babka from a stoneware baking bowl?

Tags: bread

I just baked an Easter bread (Babka - Polish sweet bread) and allowed it to cool in a stoneware round bowl.  Now I can not remove the bread from the bowl.  Any suggestions?

Comment: glazed or unglazed stoneware?  (not that I have a sure solution for either one, but I'd try a relatively stiff plastic spatula for unglazed; I'd be wary of grinding it down if unglazed)

Answer (score 1):

My sister had this exact issue last Easter, we just couldn’t get the babka out.  Eventually, she just tore out what she could using a clean pry-bar, and then let the family dog clean out the rest of the bowl.  Then she soaked the bowl in water.